# Generate script to automate renaming of default constraints

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-sql

Background: Some of our default column constraints were generated without explicit names, so we get fun names that vary from server to server like: `DF__User__TimeZoneIn__5C4D869D`

I would prefer to have them all manageable with a consistent naming like `DF_Users_TimeZoneInfo` so that we can ensure that the appropriate constraints exist on future target tables (like in RedGate compare, or even just visually)

I've got a script that mostly works for what I want:

```
select 'sp_rename N''[' + s.name + '].[' + d.name + ']'', 
   N''[DF_' + t.name + '_' + c.name + ']'', ''OBJECT'';'
from sys.tables t
    join
    sys.default_constraints d
        on d.parent_object_id = t.object_id
    join
    sys.columns c
        on c.object_id = t.object_id
        and c.column_id = d.parent_column_id
    join sys.schemas s
        on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE d.NAME like 'DF[_][_]%'
```

But this just gives me a resultset, and not something I can actually pass into an exec or whatever.

How can I make this so I can just execute those `sp_rename` scripts without having to resort to copying out all the returned elements and pasting them into a new query window and running them again? Trying to save as many keystrokes as possible so I can correct this in *many* environments.

[image]

Comment: <facepalm> You should have asked me about this the other day -- I pulled my answer from the script I have that does exactly this. :)

Comment: @JonSeigel ok, how about a level of indrection around this to run once on each of several dbs? :D

Comment: Don't put Square brackets around the new name - I ended up with a world of hurt after running this script :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, couple of things.

1. always use `EXEC` when executing stored procedures; the shorthand without `EXEC` only works when it is the first statement in the batch (and that will not be the case here).
2. [always use semi-colon terminators](https://sqlblog.org/2009/09/03/ladies-and-gentlemen-start-your-semi-colons) - in this case they are useful in lieu of pretty carriage returns and indentation, but they are always wise to have.
3. always use [`QUOTENAME()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/quotename-transact-sql) instead of manually applying square brackets yourself. In this case you're probably safe, but there are cases where the manual approach will break.
4. you can test the `PRINT` output but it won't necessarily be complete if your total command is > 8k (see [this tip for some alternative approaches](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/)).

   ```
   DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'';

   SELECT @sql += N'EXEC sys.sp_rename N''' 
       + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(d.name) 
       + ''', N''DF_' + t.name + '_' + c.name + ''', ''OBJECT'';'
     FROM sys.tables AS t
     INNER JOIN sys.default_constraints AS d
        ON d.parent_object_id = t.object_id
     INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
        ON c.object_id = t.object_id
       AND c.column_id = d.parent_column_id
     INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s
        ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
     WHERE d.NAME LIKE N'DF[_][_]%';

   PRINT @sql;
   -- EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql;
   ```

Comment: Good to know about the EXEC for each statement, I didn't know about that.

Comment: Yeah try to execute this: `sp_help; sp_help;`.

Answer (score 3):

Based on your question .. which you have removed "automate the same script on some of the databases on the instance"

Below is the code that will help you

```
set nocount on
DECLARE @table TABLE 
  ( 
     dbname VARCHAR(30) 
  ) 

INSERT INTO @table 
            (dbname) 
VALUES      ( 'dev_construct1' ), 
            ('dev_construct2'), 
            ('dev_construct3' ); 

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max) = N''; 
DECLARE @dbname VARCHAR(30) 

/*  
Added by Kin : While loop and an extra @dbname variable 
*/ 
SELECT @dbname = Min(dbname) 
FROM   @table 

WHILE @dbname IS NOT NULL 
  BEGIN 
      SELECT @sql = N'USE ' + tt.dbname + Char(10) + N' GO;'
      FROM   @table tt 
      WHERE  @dbname = dbname 

      SELECT @sql += Char(10) + N'EXEC sp_rename N''' 
                     + Quotename(s.name) + '.' + Quotename(d.name) 
                     + ''', N''DF_' + t.name + '_' + c.name 
                     + ''', ''OBJECT'';' 
      FROM   sys.tables AS t 
             JOIN sys.default_constraints d 
               ON d.parent_object_id = t.object_id 
             JOIN sys.columns c 
               ON c.object_id = t.object_id 
                  AND c.column_id = d.parent_column_id 
             JOIN sys.schemas s 
               ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id 
             JOIN @table tt 
               ON tt.dbname = tt.dbname 
      WHERE  d.name LIKE 'DF[_][_]%'; 

      PRINT @sql 

      SELECT @dbname = Min(dbname) 
      FROM   @table 
      WHERE  dbname > @dbname 
  END 
-- EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: I removed it because the previous question was missing a key bit of detail, since the column names change in each db, so I need to run the inner query per context of the individual db.

Comment: @jcolebrand thanks for the update. In any case, the code with my changes will help you what you are looking.